# System Verilog Function return value as parameterized bit vector

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I need to create a function in SystemVerilog with return value as a parameterized bit vector.
My code is as follows:

```
class my_class #(parameter ADDR_WIDTH = 32);
    bit [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] address;

    function bit [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] get_address();
        return address;
    endfunction : get_address

endclass : my_class
```

I get a compile time error in the function declaration saying that the parameter `ADDR_WIDTH` is not defined. Can anyone please explain why this is happening? The same is working without the parameter (i.e if I have a known value like `bit [31:0]`).

Comment: What is your Verilog simulator? I tried in my environment with IUS, it does not complain on the function declaration with the parameter.

Comment: I'm using questa modelsim.. I tried using typedef and it seems to work now.
`typedef bit [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] address_width_t;`
`function address_width_t get_address();`

Comment: If I try to define the function outside the class unlike above, I had to do the following:
`function my_class::address_width_t my_class::get_address();`
Seems like the compiler is unable to resolve the scope of the typedef parameter so i had to give "my_class::address_width"

Comment: What version of questa modelsim are you using? You may need to update.

Comment: Compiles fine on Questa 10.2c: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/91

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code you showed in the original example, and I've tried it on earlier versions of Questa. Usually when you get unexplainable errors on code that looks perfectly fine, you are either using a version that is too old, or the real error is on a line above the the code in question.